# Windows server 2016 services stop / start during night multiple times

Tags: windows-server-2016, service

We have an odd issue on one of our servers (Windows Server 2016) that started to occur 2 weeks ago (worked without issues for the past 4 years).
The issue is very simple, software services like SQL Server 2016, or Windows Server services like Microsoft Policy Platform Local Authority are simply stopping (successfully) and starting (successfully) from 20h to 7h MULTIPLES (~30) times per night.

I've checked everything that were done on that day and the previous days on the server that may have had an impact such as software installation, or any kinds of update.

Event Viewer shows not much prior of the issue.

Due to this issue, many jobs are failing during night.

Comment: Any logon events in the security event log? Any Backup software that does some "Application Aware Processing"?